# How to return a value from plugin to action/js?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have a button that calls an action that triggers a plugin, I want to pass a value from my plugin and show it to the user (by popup). I defined an output  parameter in my action.
How do I return the value (output parameter) I retrieved in my plugin back to my js function  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is, assign the output param in plugin code and consume it in JS calling code. [Read more](https://carldesouza.com/custom-actions-in-javascript-with-output-parameters-in-d365-and-powerapps/)

I'm showing the `Xrm.WebApi` way, but you can use `XMLHttpRequest` or ajax too.

Plugin assignment C# code:

```
context.OutputParameters["Output1"] = "blah blah";
```

Custom action calling JS code:

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.Input1 = 10;

var new_MyCustomActionReq = {
    Input1: parameters.Input1,
 
    getMetadata: function () {
        return {
            boundParameter: null,
            parameterTypes: {
                "Input1": {
                    "typeName": "Edm.Int32",
                    "structuralProperty": 1
                },
            },
            operationType: 0,
            operationName: "new_MyCustomAction"
        };
    }
};

Xrm.WebApi.online.execute(new_MyCustomActionReq).then(
    function success(result) {
        result.json().then(
            function (response) {
                var myOutput = response.Output1;
                alert(myOutput);
            }
        );
    }
    ,
    function (error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    }
);
```